# Store intersection point - Matlab

Tags: matlab, polygon, intersection

How can I store the intersection points of a polyshape and a line so I can plot it?

Script ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html#mw_e180f1ff-1958-4121-93c1-1bd73503f40c)):

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

poly1 = polyshape([0.5 0 1 1.5],[1 0 0 2]);
lineseg = [0.5 0.5; 2 2];

[in,out] = intersect(poly1,lineseg);
plot(poly1)
hold on
plot(in(:,1),in(:,2),'b',out(:,1),out(:,2),'r')
```

Comment: You've copy-pasted code from here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html#mw_e180f1ff-1958-4121-93c1-1bd73503f40c -- Please don't forget to attribute.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of that `plot` command? It is plotting lines between the points were the `lineseg` intersects `poly1`. Thus, you have those points right there in `in` and/or `out`.

Comment: I do not want to do a mistake but is xInter = in(1,1);
yInter = in(1,2);
scatter(xInter,yInter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that [`in`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html#d120e944016) contains the points forming line segments inside the polygon, and `out` contains the points forming line segments outside the polygon, I would say that any point that is in both `in` and `out` should be an intersection point.

To find these common points, use [this other `intersect` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) with the `'rows'` option:

```
pts = intersect(in, out, 'rows');
scatter(pts(:,1), pts(:,2));
```